# Express/Webpack failing on dokku and heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, webpack, dokku

Procfile:

```
build: npm run prod
web: nodemon server.js
```

Package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress --optimize-dupe"
  }
```

Webpack.prod.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: null,
  entry: [
    './assets/js/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"production"' }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/js'),
        exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/css'),
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Server.js:

```
var path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    var host = server.address().address
    console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})
```

Errors:

Dokku, 502 Bad Gateway:

```
2016/03/03 22:43:12 [error] 5419#0: *303 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.49.14.190, server: xxx.xxx, request: "GET http://testp3.pospr.waw.pl/testproxy.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.4:5000/testproxy.php", host: "testp3.pospr.waw.pl"
2016/03/03 23:54:58 [error] 5419#0: *305 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.49.14.190, server: xxx.xxx, request: "GET http://testp4.pospr.waw.pl/testproxy.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.4:5000/testproxy.php", host: "testp4.pospr.waw.pl"
2016/03/04 00:55:35 [error] 5419#0: *307 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.46.13.22, server: xxx.xxx, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.4:5000/robots.txt", host: "artempixel.com.br"
2016/03/04 00:55:41 [error] 5419#0: *309 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 207.46.13.22, server: xxx.xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.4:5000/", host: "artempixel.com.br"
```

There are no errors from Heroku's logs, only on the frontend:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - bundle.js:1
```

`npm run prod` should create a file in `/public/dist/`, like it does on my local machine, but this directory is not present on either the heroku instance or the dokku instance, no error is display that it failed to create it, but if I try `heroku run --app app mkdir public/dist` it will silently fail, as if I try to access the directory it just 'created' it does not exist. I have also tried to manually run the `npm run prod`, it is successful, no dir is created, no errors are presented.

I believe there is also an issue with what my express server is trying to serve, my `bundle.js` is being served as `index.html`, I am not sure if this is an issue with there being no `bundle.js` to serve, or, even if there was, the `app.get('*')` has been misconfigured and is serving `index.html` blindly.

I simply want a static index.html file to serve my bundle.js so React can take over and do its thing, this doesn't seem possible with heroku, so I have tried to wedge an express server in between, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, how did you fix this ? I am having a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022938/heroku-deployment-browser-console-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Answer (score 8):

I was using a block in my express server similar to the one you are using:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})
```

In production, my `bundle.js` file existed on the server, but this block was causing the browser to interpret the contents of the `bundle.js` file to be the contents of the `index.html` file, which is where there exists HTML code starting with `<`, hence the error.

For me, the error was solved in production by removing that `app.get('*')` block. I thought I needed the block in the first place to anchor request urls relative to the root url, not relative to whatever url path of the current page. It seems this is no longer an issue for me, perhaps because I included leading "/" in front of all my ajax api request urls.

This error popped up in production but not development probably because webpack dev server doesn't use an actual bundle file but holds the bundle in memory. But an actual bundle file is used in production.

Note: to get my configuration working, I also had to make sure express could recognize the bundle as a static file at the appropriate location:

```
app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

The `'/dist',` part was key, else the bundle was showing up in the root path, not the path specified by my webpack config output.

Comment: I am having the same problem and would like to use your solution but I can't figure out how the change you describe here fits into the whole context. Could you share more information about your server and app file structure?

Comment: '*'  using start would mean for every request to node the response will be html page. So if you open up your network tab in chrome and reload your browser you ll see that for bundle.js you get back a HTML file which is your index.html. So 

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client/dist/index.html"))
    });
 
and 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/dist")));

Will set up paths for default GET request on Node and Static resource routing. So it solves the thing

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

I was not using `postinstall` in my `package.json`, instead I was trying to achieve this via the `Procfile`, now that I have swapped, the dist file is created properly.

In the `index.html` serving the `bundle.js` I was looking for: `/public/dist/bundle.js`, which express would translate to: `/public/public/dist/bundle.js`.

Set up a new instance of dokku as I had, through debugging managed to screw up the container.